# upload image and already saved image, this two parts want to display on two different html template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, imagefield

I use `modelformset_factory` to upload image, but I want to separate the already saved image (`A` in the below link) and upload image (`B` in the below link) on two different html template.

How do I resolve this problem?

[image]

Here is my code below:

views.py

```
def post_image(request):

    PictureFormSet = modelformset_factory(Picture, form=PictureForm, extra=3)

        if request.method == 'POST':
    
            formset = PictureFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)
    
            if formset.is_valid():
        
                formset.save()
        
                return HttpResponse("Upload done!!")
    
            else:
        
                return HttpResponse("Upload Failed!!")

        else:
    
            formset = PictureFormSet()
    
            return render(request, "Image.html", {"formset": formset})
```

models.py

```
    class Picture(models.Model):
        article = models.ForeignKey("Article", related_name="article_photo", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="photo", height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=100)
        first_photo = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

urls.py

```
    path('post/image/', post_image),
```

html

```
    <html lang="zh-Hant-TW">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>post_image</title>
    </head>
    <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ formset.management_form }}
        <table>
            {% for form in formset %}
                {{ form }}
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Sumbit">
    </form>
```

Comment: you can render two templates to strings, join them and send to browser as one string.

Comment: but I don't know how to split two parts in views code.

Comment: I don't know if I understand but you can use [render_to_string()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/templates/#django.template.loader.render_to_string) to render two templates to strings (every template only with `form`, without `<htm>`, `<head>`) and use both in finall template which adds `<htm>`, `<head>` - `return render(request, 'base.html', content=template1_string+template2_string)`

Comment: I only use "save()" function that cause two parts in my view code.
I do not know how to present B part in view code.

Comment: I guess that present two parts function comes from "save()" base code. But i cannot find source code.